# Удаление из Elasticsearch и обновление

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть такой код

```
ESClient.delete({
        index: 'index',
        type: 'type',
        id: id
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (res) {
            get_list(input, function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
```

код ответной ф-ции тоже стандартный

```
ESClient.search({
        index: 'index',
        type: 'type',
        query: 'match_all',
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (res) {
            callback(res);
        } else {
            console.dir(err);
            callback(err);
        }
    });
```

Проблема в том что ответом приходит ещё не удалённая таблица , то есть ответом я получаю таблицу с уже удалённым значением , и приходится делать вручную обновление, можно как то сделать запрос чтобы получить ответ исключая удалённое значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch - это не база данных в привычном понимании. Это - near-realtime поисковая машина, которая имеет полное право выдавать неконсистентные значения в течение пяти минут после изменения. И, на самом деле, большое чудо, что она вообще изменяемая - большинство индексовых движков требуют полную замену индекса для обновления результатов поискового запроса; индекс, сам по себе - неизменяемая коллекция данных, и создателям ES/Lucene пришлось сильно попотеть, чтобы поисковая машина вообще обновлялась время от вермени.

Первое, о чем нужно подумать в этой ситуации - это нужно ли вам вообще как-то связываться с этим временным лагом. Пятиминутная задержка в поисковой выдаче обычно не замечается никем, а возможность совершить переход на страницу сущности, которая в это время была удалена, есть всегда. Тем не менее, процесс все-таки можно ускорить.

Внутренние индексы ES состоят из сегментов - микроиндексов, выделенных под каждые N документов. Когда добавляется новый документ, ES перестраивает ровно один сегмент индекса, избавляясь от необходимости перестраивать и блокировать весь индекс целиком. Тем не менее, это не бесплатная процедура, которая происходит асинхронно, и из-за которой (скорее всего, но не точно) вообще появился этот вопрос. Поэтому ElasticSearch сначала добавляет документ в очередь на обновление сегмента, а раз в пять минут этот сегмент сохраняется на диск и перестраивается на уровне Lucene. Т.к. целевые задачи ElasticSearch предполагают бешеное количество запросов, постоянно синхронизировать файлы индексов просто недопустимо, и эта операция была вынесена в асинхронное исполнение, а при поиске документа по id ElasticSearch будет использовать сначала сегмент индекса, а потом очередь еще не сохраненных документов, чтобы найти документ (поэтому вы можете видеть "фантомные" чтения - документ доступен по идентификатору, но в выдаче его нет). Однако процесс можно немного ускорить: Lucene хранит свои индексы как на диске, так и (очевидно) в памяти, поэтому можно принудить Lucene объединить все сегменты с их очередями, не вызывая записи на диск - и для этого существует метод [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html). Это условно-бесплатная операция (дешевле, чем сразу писать на диск), но вынос ее в отдельную ручку API создателями ElasticSearch подсказывает мне, что она все-таки может быть ресурсоемка и/или блокирует поисковый индекс.

Отмечу, что также существует операция flush, которая принудительно сбросит все данные на диск. Как говорилось выше, это дорогая операция, которую нужно вызывать только в экстремальных случаях (например, перед выключением узла).

Резюмируя: попробуйте использовать операцию refresh для вашего индекса.

[Вопрос на enso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19973721/2908793), через который я все это узнал.

Comment: да даже если сделать обновление вручную через пол секунды , то всё уже показывает как удалённое, может  есть какая ф-ция которая сделает калбек когда объект будет удалён, или можно сделать атрибут который внесёт такую задержку

Comment: @vnn198 refresh и есть такой коллбек, это синхронный метод, он не вернет вам значение, пока весь индекс не будет обновлен

Comment: пробую через bulk, но может я просто не так делаю refresh, вот так делаю Client.bulk({
            body: [
                { delete: { _index: 'myindex', _type: 'mytype', _id: id } },
                { refresh: { _index: 'myindex'} }
            ]
        }